# Natural examples of multiplicatively-graded rings

Tags: examples-counterexamples, graded-rings

A ring $A$ is *multiplicatively graded* if, as an additive group, it decomposes as

$$A=\bigoplus_{n\geq 1} A_n$$

and the product satisfies $A_n \times A_m \rightarrow A_{nm}$.

A natural example of such a ring is the ring of Dirichlet polynomials:

$$A=\mathbf{C}[1^s, 2^s, 3^s, \dots]$$

with $\deg(n^s)=n$, $1^s=1$. More generally, if $M$ is a monoid equipped with a monoid morphism $\deg : M \to (\mathbf{N}_{>0}, \times)$, then the monoid algebra $\mathbf C[M]$ has a natural structure of multiplicatively graded algebra.

Are there other examples of such objects which arise naturally in mathematics?

Comment: Your second example is not a ring; composition only distributes over multiplication on the left, not the right.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Over addition, right? But yes, indeed... thanks!

Comment: Judging by @QiaochuYuan's comment, you're interested in univariate polynomials with respect to addition and composition. If so, then you may want to read up about additively-commutative [near-rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-ring). We might call $(\mathbf{C}[x],+,\circ)$ an "additively-commutative multiplicatively-graded near-$\mathbf{C}$-algebra" or something like that.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal, I fixed the answer.